# PriorityBlockingQueue logically unbounded but not actually?

Tags: java, memory, collections, out-of-memory

In the specification of [PriorityBlockingQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/PriorityBlockingQueue.html), it says:

> While this queue is logically unbounded, attempted additions may fail
>   due to resource exhaustion (causing OutOfMemoryError).

Are there any collection classes that permit storage of unbounded objects without getting resources exhaustion or `OutOfMemoryError`?

Comment: Umwell, no. You exhaust the heap, you exhaust the heap... Or you run out of address space... Or you trigger the gc overhead limit... No code is immune to that, collection or anything else. Or do you have a more precise concern in mind?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, because the amount of matter available for computational purposes is finite (seriously).

Comment: @dog, I actually went to Google to find out, and current consensus in physics seems to be "assumed infinite". So I'll edit my answer.